# Treat all section commands as labls

Tags: sectioning, labels

Is there a way to ask LaTeX to treat all chapters, sections, sub sections, etc as de facto labels instead of having to manually add labels tags everywhere like so:

```
\chapter{Introduction} \label{Introduction}
```

Comment: `\newcommand\mychap[1]{\chapter{#1}\label{#1}}`   ... `\mychap{Introduction}` but you lose much of the point of `\label` doing that, an editorial change to a section heading would mean that you have to locate and edit every cross reference to the section, which is exactly what `\ref` mechanism was designed to avoid.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle `\newcommand\mychap[2][you forgot the label again]{\chapter{#2}\label{#1}}`  for a nice `duplicate label : you forgot the label again` warning ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it, even keeping the standard syntax.

```
\documentclass{book}

\NewCommandCopy{\latexchapter}{\chapter}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{sO{#3}m}{%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}}
    {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}\label{#3}}%
}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}

This is chapter~\ref{Introduction}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this is not something I recommend doing. Actually I recommend ***not*** doing it.

Think about it: if you change your mind and decide that the “Introduction” chapter has actually to be titled “Introduction and preliminary results”, then you will have to chase the document for occurrences of `\ref{Introduction}` and change them to

```
\ref{Introduction and preliminary results}
```

Later, you're advised by your supervisor that the title should be “Introduction, with some preliminary results”. New chase.

There is ***no*** advantage in automatic labels, and ***several*** disadvantages.

If you do

```
\chapter{Introduction}\label{intro}
```

then you can change the title without worrying that cross-references will have to be modified.

Comment: When are we getting a keyval-based system instead, e.g. `\chapter{Introduction}[label=chap:intro]`? Wasn’t this part of the plans with the `xtemplate` system?

Comment: I’m not sure it’s easier or clearer than using `\label`

Comment: I think it is. A keyval approach allows you to set so many more options in a clearer and more structured way, which is why we are using keyval syntax in the first place. I have the impression that ConTeXt has already switched to this kind of interface for its chapter commands.